# How to fill a cell using one formula or another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to fill a cell(G7) using either the formula G5/B2 or (G6/(B2/1000)). I've done some searching but can't seem to find any information on how to make this work. In the sheet I'm trying to make it to where you can input into G5 or G6 and get an answer. B2 will always be a constant and never change. Has anyone ever done this before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if()`, like this:

```
=if( isnumber(G5), G5 / B2, G6 / (B2 / 1000) )
```

Replace `isnumber(G5)` with the condition you want to use to choose between the two alternatives.

Comment: Either G5 or G6 will have a number input into the cell. If G5 is the cell I enter the number, then i would need to use G5/G2. If G6 has the number entered it needs to use G6/(B2/1000). I'm not sure how to write that condition out.

Comment: Edited the answer per your new requirements.